# запустить apache после рестарта

Tags: php, apache, apache2

выполняю в php скрипте

```
exec("sudo service apache2 restart", $output);
```

служба вырубается, но чтобы ее запустить надо делать это вручную в isp manager.

можно ли это сделать через php скрипт?
почему служба не стартует по команде рестарта?

мягкий перезапуск reload в моей ситуации не помогает;

upd. даны права на запуск sudo из php- скрипта (www-data    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL). т.е reload нормально отрабатывает, а restart по сути работает только как stop.

Comment: Посмотрите, что пишется в логи, просто так рестарт обрываться не будет

Comment: var/log/apache2/error -пишет только одно предупреждение     [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down.

Comment: ручной вызов того же самого отрабатывает?

Comment: не понял вопроса. при рестарте служба вырубается (stop), автоматически после этого старт службы не происходит. вручную через isp manager все работает, конечно, в обычном порядке.

Comment: я имею в виду выполнение той же команды от того же пользователя из консоли

Comment: Вывод команды передается в переменную `$output`, посмотрите что  в ней. Либо выполните команду в консоли от юзера `www-data`, тогда точно ошибку увидите.

Comment: @Prog2010 , насколько я понял, вы из программы *apache* пытаетесь выполнить скрипт (`/etc/init.d/apache2`), который **останавливает** программу *apache*. **всё**. на этом выполнение программы *apache* прекращается и что бы там ни было предусмотрено дальше в скрипте, это не будет выполнено.

Comment: @Prog2010, вам надо как-то *извне* программы пытаться перезапускать эту самую программу.

Comment: @Prog2010 , `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` — это **очень** плохая идея. программа *apache* выполняется от **непривилегированного** пользователя отнюдь не из глупого каприза мэйнтэйнера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов перезапуска процесса - определяется версией операционки и сервера. Например, у меня работает:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Еще вариант:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
```